# Properly importing Apache Storm dependencies in Clojure

Tags: clojure, redis, apache-storm

I am try to use Apache Storm and Redis in my Clojure project. My `project.clj` looks like this:

```
(defproject storm "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.apache.storm/storm-core "0.9.5"]
                 [com.taoensso/carmine "2.11.1"] ])
```

And namespace declaration in the Redis connector module is:

```
(ns storm.redis
  (:require [taoensso.carmine :as car]))
```

Now, for some reason, if i try to evaluate the above namespace declaration, i get a weird error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.Exception: namespace 'taoensso.carmine' not found, compiling:(storm/redis.clj:1:22)
```

If i modify the Storm dependency in `project.clj` to

```
[storm "0.9.0.1"] ; Last available version on Clojars
```

then everything works properly. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found a solution. Running `lein deps :tree` gave me this:

```
Possibly confusing dependencies found:
[org.apache.storm/storm-core "0.9.5"] -> [commons-codec "1.6"]
 overrides
[com.taoensso/carmine "2.11.1"] -> [commons-codec "1.10"]

Consider using these exclusions:
[com.taoensso/carmine "2.11.1" :exclusions [commons-codec]]
```

Excluding `commons-codec` from `carmine` still produced the same error, but doing it vice versa and excluding from `storm` worked:

```
[org.apache.storm/storm-core "0.9.5" :exclusions [commons-codec]]
```

So this means that both libraries will use the newer version of `commons-codec`.

Seems that `carmine` failed to initialise itself (?) due to lower version of the dependency. This is just a conjecture, as i don't know how to debug those library initialisation routines.

**UPDATE:** Peter Taoussanis, author of Carmine library, in response to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine/issues/142) confirmed that this is a dependency problem and also suggested some other methods of fixing similar problems. Thanks Peter!